# Getting the full tag name of children

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, xbrl

I want to get the entire tag name from the XBRL.

```
<us-gaap:TaxAdjustmentsSettlementsAndUnusualProvisions
```

What I am getting is TaxAdjustmentsSettlementsAndUnusualProvisions but I want to catch us-gaap as well.

I am using python's Etree library for this.

### Example 1.1

```
for elem in tree.iter():
    print(elem)
```

#### output

```
<Element '{http://fasb.org/us-gaap/2018-01-31}TaxAdjustmentsSettlementsAndUnusualProvisions' at 0x7ff7e29ef0e8>
```

### Example 1.2

```
for elem in tree.iter():
    print(elem.tag)
```

#### output

```
{http://fasb.org/us-gaap/2018-01-31}TaxAdjustmentsSettlementsAndUnusualProvisions
```

What i am looking for is a way to catch both us-gaap and TaxAdjustmentsSettlementsAndUnusualProvisions.

Comment: Please share the code + xml

Comment: @balderman  well I have elaborated the problem as per requirements.

Comment: @RajdeepSengupta Where is the XML? Add a parseable XML please.

Comment: Why do you need the tag?

Comment: Look here https://pypi.org/project/python-xbrl/ It may work for you

Comment: `{http://fasb.org/us-gaap/2018-01-31}TaxAdjustmentsSettlementsAndUnusualProvisions` **is** the full tag name. Please explain why you need to get `us-gaap`, which in the XML file is the **prefix** associated with the `http://fasb.org/us-gaap/2018-01-31` namespace URI. A namespace prefix is arbitrary; what really matters is the namespace URI. ElementTree does not care about the prefix and discards it. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml-with-namespaces.

Comment: With lxml, you can use `elem.prefix`.

Comment: @mzjn while it is correct that in XML the prefix does not matter as it is only a proxy to the namespace, the XBRL community, by convention refers to names with their prefixes rather than their namespaces, because these names are heavily used in communication (oral, e-mail, documentation, etc) between XBRL users. This is viable because there are conventions to stick to the same prefixes for any given namespace. In this case, everybody, in the XBRL community, understands that the us-gaap prefix is used for the US GAAP taxonomy, published by the FASB. Also, the namespace changes every year.

Comment: @GhislainFourny: Thanks, good to know.